# How to compress http request on the fly and without loading compressed buffer in memory

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, compression, gzip, dotnet-httpclient

I need to send voluminous data in a http post request to a server supporting gziped encoded requests.

Starting from a simple

```
public async Task<string> DoPost(HttpContent content)
{
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://myUri", content);

  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

I've just added a pre compression

```
public async Task<string> DoPost(HttpContent content, bool compress)
{
  if (compress) 
    content= await CompressAsync(content);

  return await DoPost(content);
}

private static async Task<StreamContent> CompressAsync(HttpContent content)
{
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
  {
    await content.CopyToAsync(gzipStream);
    await gzipStream.FlushAsync();
  }

  ms.Position = 0;
  StreamContent compressedStreamContent = new StreamContent(ms);
  compressedStreamContent.Headers.ContentType = content.Headers.ContentType;
  compressedStreamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

  return compressedStreamContent;
}
```

It works perfectly but compress data are completly loaded into memory before sending request. I **would like to be able to compress data on the fly during sending in a streaming way.**

To do it, I've tried following code:

```
private static async Task<HttpContent> CompressAsync2(HttpContent content)
{
  PushStreamContent pushStreamContent = new PushStreamContent(async (stream, content2, transport) =>
  {
    using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    {
      try
      {
        await content.CopyToAsync(gzipStream);
        await gzipStream.FlushAsync();
      }
      catch (Exception exception)
      {
        throw;
      }
    }
  });
  pushStreamContent.Headers.ContentType = content.Headers.ContentType;
  pushStreamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

  return pushStreamContent;
}
```

**but it never goes out of CopyToAsync(gzipStream)**. FlushAsync is never executed and no exception is thrown and Fiddler don't see any post started.

My questions are:

- Why CompressAsync2 doesn't work?
- How to compress on the fly during sending and without loading compressed buffer in memory?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `PushStreamContent` does not (currently) support `async` lambdas.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary: You've right, I should have checked! And I can't derived from PushStreamContent to overload SerializeToStreamAsync (too many internal only). can you see a solution?

Comment: Humm, it may be easiest to just take [`PushStreamContent` and modify it](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/PushStreamContent.cs) to support `async` lambdas. It's been on my "todo" list for a few months now, just haven't gotten around to it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using the CompressedContent class from WebAPIContrib https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/blob/master/src/WebApiContrib/Content/CompressedContent.cs

```
public async Task<string> DoPost(HttpContent content)
{
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://myUri", 
                                 new CompressedContent(content,"gzip"));

  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

P.S. that this will only stream the content on .net 4.5.  The .net 4 version of HttpWebRequest always buffers sent content.

P.P.S. Creating a new HttpClient for each request is not the best way to use HttpClient.  Doing this will force a new TCP connection to be created for each request.

Comment: Really interresting link: thanks a lot. I need to stay on .Net 4.0 (XP needed). Do you think I can get streamed when .Net 4.5 is installed even if I compile for .Net 4.0?

Comment: I've created a local HttpClient only for question simplicity.

Comment: @MuiBienCarlota I'm not sure.  My guess would be yes, but you need to test.  Regarding the HttpClient... cool, I just see it a lot and I'm on a mission to stamp it out ;-)

Comment: I have the answer: it's No. When compiled for .Net 4.0 , we are not in a streaming way (even when .Net 4.5 is present). I will try under .Net 4.5.

Comment: It works when targeting .Net 4.5 and not when targeting .Net 4.0 even with .Net 4.5 is present. It surprise me. I was thinking that .Net 4.5 was a complete replacement of .Net 4.0 ie if 4.5 is installed, my program targeting 4.0 should be running under 4.5. Mysterious!

Comment: Answer accepted: only possible in .Net 4.5 due to HttpWebRequest .NEt 4.0 limitation and without forgotting Stephen Cleary's answer on my first question (no lambda support on PushStreamContent).