# What is the best way to compress a request to asp.net core 2 site using HttpClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-core-2.0

I am sending request that can be significantly big(~1Mb) and I am seeing a large delay betweeen when I make the request and when asp.net core logs that it is handling the request. I think I can cut down this time by compressing the request to asp using gzip.

Below is the fairly straight forward way that I am making requests without compression. What is the proper way to implement Gzip request compression on the client requesting side, and once I implement it on the client, what do I need to do for the server side?

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("Controller/Action", httpContent).Result)
{
    if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {

        throw new Exception(string.Format("Invalid responsecode for http request response {0}: {1}", response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So I got it to work with simple middleware on the server side and not too much work on the client side. I used [CompressedContent.cs from WebAPIContrib](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/blob/master/src/WebApiContrib/Content/CompressedContent.cs), as Rex suggested in the comments of his answer, and made the request as shown below. The whole throw-exception-if-not-OK is because I am using Polly wrapped around my request with a Retry and wait policy.

Client Side:

```
using (var httpContent = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
using (var compressedContent = new CompressedContent(httpContent, "gzip"))
using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("Controller/Action", compressedContent).Result)
{
    if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Invalid responsecode for http request response {0}: {1}", response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase));
    }
}
```

Then on the server side I created a simple piece of middleware that wraps the request body stream with the Gzip stream. To use it, you need to add the line `app.UseMiddleware<GzipRequestMiddleware>();` **before** the call to `app.UseMvc();` in your `Startup.cs`'s `Configure` method.

```
public class GzipRequestMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;
    private const string ContentEncodingHeader = "Content-Encoding";
    private const string ContentEncodingGzip = "gzip";
    private const string ContentEncodingDeflate = "deflate";

    public GzipRequestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Headers.Keys.Contains(ContentEncodingHeader) && (context.Request.Headers[ContentEncodingHeader] == ContentEncodingGzip || context.Request.Headers[ContentEncodingHeader] == ContentEncodingDeflate))
        {
            var contentEncoding = context.Request.Headers[ContentEncodingHeader];
            var decompressor = contentEncoding == ContentEncodingGzip ? (Stream)new GZipStream(context.Request.Body, CompressionMode.Decompress, true) : (Stream)new DeflateStream(context.Request.Body, CompressionMode.Decompress, true);
            context.Request.Body = decompressor;
        }
        await next(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to enable compression as shown below

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();  
if (handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)  
{
    handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
}

var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

MSDN Reference: [Using automatic decompression with HttpClient](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2013/06/06/portable-compression-and-httpclient-working-together/)

Comment: A msdn reference link would be perfect

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2013/06/06/portable-compression-and-httpclient-working-together/

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but that looks like it would only handle response decompression and not request compression, right?

Comment: @Theyouthis - Right. This adds additional Accept-Encoding header in request from client to server indicating server that it supports compressed response. But to enable compressed request then it would be done using CompressedContent class from WebAPIContrib with few limitations in the framework https://stackoverflow.com/a/16674884/7630979