# Request decompression middleware error (InvalidDataException) for gzip encoding (.net 8)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, compression, gzip, .net-8.0

## Client side

TargetFramework: *netstandard2.0*. Also tested on *.net8* 
OS: Windows 10 
The request is maded by HttpClient from the windows application. Source code:

```
Test(someHostName, someSecretePath, jsonContent);

private static void Test(string host, string url, string jsonContent)
{
    var client = new HttpClient()
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(host)
    };
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = new HttpMethod("Post"),
        RequestUri = new Uri(url),
    };
    request.Content = new StringContent(Compress(jsonContent), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    request.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("gzip");

    using var result = client.Send(request);
}

private static string Compress(string inputStr)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inputStr);
    using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var gs = new GZipStream(mso, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
            {
                msi.CopyTo(gs);
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(mso.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

## Server side

TargetFramework: *net8.0* 
Hosting: Kestrel 
Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddRequestDecompression();
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

    var app = builder.Build();

    app.UseRequestDecompression();
    app.MapControllers();
    app.Run();
}
```

## Debugging server side

#### Http request

```
Protocol: HTTP/1.1
Method: POST
Scheme: http
PathBase: 
Path: /someSecretPath
Host: someSecretHost
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 236
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

#### Logs from debug window:

```
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.RequestDecompression.DefaultRequestDecompressionProvider[4]
      **The request will be decompressed with 'gzip'**.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'WebApiNet8.Controllers.SomeController.CreateAsync (WebApi)'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[25]
      Connection id "0HN11D3HP3G05", Request id "0HN11D3HP3G05:00000001": started reading request body.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[26]
      Connection id "0HN11D3HP3G05", Request id "0HN11D3HP3G05:00000001": done reading request body.
Exception thrown: "System.IO.InvalidDataException" в System.Private.CoreLib.dll

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.IO.InvalidDataException: **The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.**
         at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Inflate(FlushCode flushCode)
         at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.ReadInflateOutput(Byte* bufPtr, Int32 length, FlushCode flushCode, Int32& bytesRead)
         at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.ReadOutput(Byte* bufPtr, Int32 length, Int32& bytesRead)
         at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.InflateVerified(Byte* bufPtr, Int32 length)
         at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.<ReadAsyncMemory>g__Core|51_0(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at SizeLimitedStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

In logs I can see that decompression middleware has been found the proper decompression provider and created stream. But in stream's read method it hapend a error of reading data.

## Question

Does anyone know what could be causing such problem? How can this be avoided?

Comment: Fundamentally, your request *isn't* a gzip-encoded request. It's "gzip and then base64 encoded". Compressed data isn't string data - it's arbitrary binary data, so you shouldn't use `StringContent`, but `ByteArrayContent` or similar. Or just use the code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654577...

Comment: Jon Skeet, you are right! That was a misstake. I've changed as you suggested and it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

gzip compressed data is binary data instead of string
Try this

```
private static byte[] Compress(string inputStr)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputStr); // Use UTF-8 instead of Unicode
    using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var gs = new GZipStream(mso, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            gs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        return mso.ToArray(); // Send the binary data directly
    }
}
```

Also you might need to change your test method

```
request.Content = new ByteArrayContent(compressedData);
```